# Is it secure to store Google or Facebook Oauth access Token in AsyncStorage for Login Authentication in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, oauth, oauth-2.0, passport.js

I need to implement a persistent and secure oauth2.0 login authentication with google and facebook in a react native app. In the React Navigation guide to authentication flow, it suggests to use AsyncStorage token. I read some posts that say AsyncStorage is not secure for storing data. Is AsyncStorage secure from XSS and CSRF attacks? I'm using mern stack with passport.js on this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React native says: "*AsyncStorage is an unencrypted, asynchronous, persistent, key-value storage system that is global to the app.*"
You can read this to find out more: https://reactnative.dev/docs/asyncstorage